# Is it possible to write automation test for app with google authenticator

Tags: javascript, automation, google-authentication, multi-factor-authentication, cypress

We are implementing mfa(multi factor auth) for our app and I'm trying to write automation test to test this.
I don't see any direct way to get the google authenticator code for the user to login.

Has anyone tried to do this?

Comment: The way I would probably do it would involve making the mfa module configable in the build, then swapping out the google one with a static one during testing.

Comment: Assuming you're using the common TOTP (Time-based One Time Passwords) algorithm, which I believe Google Authenticator uses, and you're able to use the test user's secret in the tests, you can either [generate the token by hand](http://jacob.jkrall.net/totp), or use a library like [Speakeasy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speakeasy) to generate the token.

Comment: are you specifically trying to test the MFA, or you don't care and simply wish to test the app (thus the authentication itself can be mocked)?

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi Speakeasy requires you to scan the QR code.

Comment: @Shadow using static is good but it would be my option, if nothing else works.

Comment: @Dwelle  Im trying to test the app ,
I want to be able to get the google authenticator code without requiring to use a phone or email. Kind of generate the code and use it 
or show on screen or any existing google api Ic an use to get the code something like that. Basically get the code, without using external device.

Comment: @uhdam what do you mean by `code`? Why not skip the auth altogether and create the auth cookie directly?

Comment: @uhdam You should be able to pass it the secret directly and [generate a time-based token](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speakeasy#getting-a-time-based-token-for-the-current-time), rather than scanning a QR code. However, if you're just trying to test the app itself, why not disable MFA for the test account, or create a dummy MFA.

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi I tried the method of generate by hand and speakeasy both. But it doesn't seem to be generating valid token

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi Thanks! speakeasy worked fine.

Comment: Glad to hear it @uhdam. :)

Answer (score 1):

**There is a package for that...**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/totp-generator is a package that can help you with the google auth tokens. Keep in mind you want to request these right when you need them. Javascript executes asynchronously so you'll need to wrap it in a promise. Here is some example code that assumes a UI login followed by the token input.

```js
describe('check the tokens', function() 
{
// First test 
it('cy.window() - get the global window object', () => { cy.viewport(500, 780) 
  cy.visit('https://site.domain',) 
  cy.get('input[name=email]').type('email@server.io') 
  cy.get('input[name=password]').focus().type('qwerty123') 
  cy.get('.Button').click()
  // Now lets wait on an object that appears on the page 
  // when ready to input the token
    cy.get(<someElement>).then(()=>{
        let token = getToken();
        console.log('first token: ' + token);
    })
})
//Second test
it('cy.window() - get the global window object', () => { cy.viewport(500, 780) 
  cy.visit('https://site.domain',) 
  cy.get('input[name=email]').type('email@server.io') 
  cy.get('input[name=password]').focus().type('qwerty123') 
  cy.get('.Button').click()
  // Now lets wait on an object that appears on the page 
  // when ready to input the token
    cy.get(<someOtherElement>).then(()=>{
        let token = getToken();
        console.log('second token: '+ token);
    });
})
})

function getToken () {
    const totp = require('totp-generator');
    const token = totp('2CQQGPPYFE7JPJAX');
    return token;
}
```